# Multiple Asynchronous Socket response handling using Mocha

Tags: node.js, sockets, mocha.js, should.js

I am trying to prototype a load testing scenario on socket interactions using Mocha and should.js. I have an array of user details which I want to authenticate using socket communication and wish to verify their responses. It works fine for a single user, however when I try to loop for multiple users - I end up with issues. Had gathered some inputs based on the post:[Tests from looping through async JavaScript (Mocha)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798049/tests-from-looping-through-async-javascript-mocha) .

Below is the code snippet:

```
var users = [{name:'A',password:'password',expected:'success'},{name:'B',password:'badPass',expected:'failure'}];
describe('socket Interaction test' , function() {
    function socketInteraction(users, done) {
        client.emit('userAuthentication', {'name':users.name,'password':users.password}, function(callback) {
            console.log('Emit' + users.name);
        });

        client.on('userAuthenticationResponse', function(response) {
            console.log('Resp' + response.status + 'Expected' + users.expected);
            response.status.should.equal(users.expected);
            done();
        });
    }

    it('Dummy', function(done) {
        describe('Mutiple login Test Async', function() {
            it('User Login Test', function(done) {
                users.forEach(function(users, callback) {
                    console.log(users.name);
                    socketInteraction(users, function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            return;
                        }
                        done();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The response I get upon running the test is:

```
 socket Interaction test
    ✓ Dummy
  Mutiple login Test Async
A
B
RespsuccessExpectedsuccess
    ✓ User Login Test
RespsuccessExpectedfailure
  2 passing (43ms)
```

The second test has to fail. Not sure where I have messed up the code. Appreciate some pointers to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The done Parma should be called in the second param of the async.forEach. The done you call in the loop function should be callback(), to tell async that just that user is finished.
You don't have the async finished callback yet at all.

Would have posted code but am on my phone. I can add later if it's not clear.

Comment: I did try to add the done as the second parameter and have included the call to the callback instead of done(). It resulted in a new set of issues.Appreciate if you could outline the changes in a little more detail. Thanks.

Comment: Another thing I see is that you have mixed your describe() and it() a bit. You should let describe's be a wrapper for it's. And don't put an it() inside another it. You overwrite the outer it's done function, so that test never gets finished. Please update with the new code if you see more problems.