# Mocha - Failed looping through array that gets initialized in before()

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Consider this test setup:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var fs = require('fs');

describe('my test', function() {

    var dataArr;

    // get data
    before(function(done) {
        fs.readFile('myArray.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            dataArr = JSON.parse(data);
            done();
        });
    });

    // test data
    dataArr.forEach(function(val, index) {
        it('Testing element no ' + (index+1), function(done) {
            expect(val).to.be.cool;
            done();
        });
    });

});
```

This test returns the error `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` because the loop is executed before `before()`.

I found [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798049/tests-from-looping-through-async-javascript-mocha) on SO which uses nested `it`s, but that seems to be a dirty workaround (googling `mocha nested it` proves that).

Isn't there any clean solution for this not so uncommon (?) problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any any cleaner solutions exist.

In your example, dataArr is undefined at the time it is evaluated, that is the member forEach doesn't yet exist because dataArr is not yet an array at that point. It would be defined inside the it()'s callback function scope as the it() callback function is called after the 'before' callback.

So the nested "describe-it" workaround works because it fixes the evaluation order such that dataArr is defined at that point.

So the already mentioned workaround is like this:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var fs = require('fs');

describe('my test', function() {

    var dataArr;

    // get data
    before(function(done) {
        dataArr =  ["cool", "cool", "cool"]; // or fs.readFile or require
        done();
    });

    // test it

    it('test after data setup', function() {
        describe('the tests', function() {
            // now the dataArr is defined!
            dataArr().forEach(function(val, index) {
                it('Testing element no ' + (index+1), function(done) {
                    assert.equal(val, "cool");
                    done();
                });
            });
        }); 
    });
});
```

On the other hand if you don't alter the dataArr, you could evaluate it at once on spot of the declaration like:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var fs = require('fs');

describe('my test', function() {

    const dataArr = ["cool", "cool", "cool"]; // or dataArr = require('testfile.json');

    before(function(done) {

        done();
    });

    // test it

    // now the dataArr is defined!
    dataArr().forEach(function(val, index) {
        it('Testing element no ' + (index+1), function(done) {
            assert.equal(val, "cool");
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tests are defined synchronously. It is test function that is postponed by asynchronous `done` call, not  `dataArr.forEach`.

In this case asynchronous `readFile` provides no benefits. It would be simpler with:

```
before(function() {
    const data = fs.readFileSync('myArray.json', 'utf8');
    dataArr = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

And there's no need for `readFile` at all. Reading the file isn't a part of a test and should be performed once. Node.js natively supports importing JSON files:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var dataArr = require('./myArray.json');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the `forEach` method out of mocha's hands, you should move all your logic inside `it` method

So update your code like below:

```
it('Testing elements', function(done) {
    expect(dataArr).all.to.be.cool;
});
```